# External javascript can not display cookie

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

For some reason every time I try to run

```
document.cookie = "name=Alan";
document.cookie = "favorite_food=tripe";
alert(document.cookie);
```

in external JavaScript and in document. I get display nothing and in console it display "";

Comment: What do you mean by *in external JavaScript on in document*

Comment: @Mike Christensen: I meant I tried it in both External JS document and  indocument of the HTML page

Comment: Are the page and script requested with `http://`? Or, perhaps `file://`? Cookies are bound to the host/domain and `file://` doesn't have one.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski I have been using file:// to call it

Comment: Well there's your problem.

Comment: It is requested with file://

Comment: @is there a way to display the cookies when calling it with file://

Comment: @JonathanLonowski - You should post as an answer.

Comment: @Gibson [Not consistently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949978/document-cookie-not-storing-cookie). You'll want to setup an HTTP/HTTPS server to host the files and request them from it.